# UserPrincipal.ChangePassword Throwing PasswordException

Tags: c#, active-directory, change-password

I have a password reset page that I created for my employees and for the `UserPrincipal` object, I perform the following:

```
UserPrincipal user = Helpers.LDAPHelper.GetUserPrincipal(model.EmailAddress);

string temporary = Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 4);

user.SetPassword(temporary);
user.ChangePassword(temporary, model.ConfirmPassword);
```

The `user.SetPassword` call works fine, but does not trigger that the password has changed, so any password age tracking that I do (to remind users to reset their password before it expires) does not work.  So, I wanted to since the `ChangePassword` method requires the current password, I set a temporary password and then use that as the current.  BUT, it throws a `PasswordException` every time:

> "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check
>   the minimum password length, password complexity and password history
>   requirements. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708C5)"

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Oh, I forgot to include the Group Policy settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the new password that is throwing the exception, is the new one a string? Also, could there be password policy other than that one such as a default policy.

Comment: The new password is at least 6 characters long.  That's the only requirement of the new password.  The only policy being applied is via group policy.  I have looked through the other policies in place and none of them have these settings defined.

Comment: The only other thing I think to check is the local policies on the server (not gpedit)

Comment: I'm not sure yet, but am verifying what this post mentions:
https://superuser.com/questions/1072610/enforced-group-policy-object-not-applying-on-windows-10

Comment: Well, after investigating further, we had a rogue tech that created another policy (with an obscure name) that set the password requirements as well. After deleting that policy, all is well. Sorry to waste other's time.